# Why do I loose new line character when I load text from a java servlet to JTextPane?

Tags: java, string, servlets, jtextpane

I try to load content of a text file that contains some text in multiple lines using java servlet.
When I test servlet in browser it works fine. Text is loaded with new line chars.
But when I load it to a string in my swing application and then use `textpane.setText(text);` new lines are gone. I tried many solutions I found int the net, but still can't get it right.

Servlet Code:
Reading text from file (simplified):

```
File file = new File(path);
StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();   
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    data.append(line);
    data.append("\n");
}
in.close();
```

Sending text:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.write(text));
```

Is it some platform issue? Servlet was writen and compiled on Linux, but I run it on Windows (on JBoss). Textfiles are also stored on my machine.

Comment: If on windows try data.append("\r\n") instead of \n

Comment: I tried this and it isnt' working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `data.append("\n")` use

```
data.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Comment: Maybe you can debug the `text` variable before writing. How does the line separator look?

Comment: Separator is '\n' and before sending text is fine. Also when I open file that I saved on disk using this servlet (It works both ways) in notepad I don't have new lines, but when I open the same file in WordPad everything is ok. I think there's a simple bug somewhere and I really can't find it:/