# New line in file

Tags: java, servlets, file-io

In a Servlet, I am using the following code to download the file. The next line characters "\n\r" are not working. Instead of new line, it showing boxes. Can any one help to solve this problem?

```
String temp = "hello"+"\n\r"+"welcome";
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=sample.txt");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();                 
out.write(temp);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302837/why-do-i-loose-new-line-character-when-i-load-text-from-a-java-servlet-to-jtextp

Comment: I have tested your code (on windows 7) and it works (printing "welcome" on a new line, without showing boxes) with: String temp = "hello"+"\n"+"welcome";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of hard-coding new line characters, you can just use the [`println`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println(java.lang.String)) method:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("hello");
out.println("welcome");
```

If this is not appropriate for some reason, you might consider obtaining the line separator from the [`line.separator` System property](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()):

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

Comment: The server side default line separator is not necessarily supported or the same for the client side. For example, the server might run Unix while the client runs Windows and the client would then still get the Unix default line separator `\n` instead of Windows default line separator `\r\n` (both should work equally good however). OP's problem lies actually somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you shelley. its very useful to me.

Answer (score 2):

The Dos/Windows format for newline is CR LF (\r\n) then:
try to replace \n\r with \r\n.

Or if you are in a unix environment you can try only \n.

Comment: And where do you suppose to receive that output? A browser? A text file? Please add some details to your question.

Comment: +1 for good answer.
I tested with "\n" and it works on windows 7. Also with "\r\n" is working.

Comment: in browser i need to get the output. the file is generating perfectly and the content also placed in the file but the thing is instead of new line it showing boxes.